# How to compact the result of a query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with two columns, CODE and LINE NUMBER:

```
201 1
201 2
202 2
203 1
203 3
204
205 1
205 2
205 4
```

etc etc...

with the query I write I get this grid:

```
201 1 2 - -
202 - 2 - -
203 1 - 3 -
204 - - - -
205 1 2 - 4
```

This is my query (sql server):

```
TRANSFORM sum(numriga)
SELECT codice
FROM tabella
GROUP BY codice
PIVOT numriga In (1,2,3,4,5);
```

Is possible with sql obtain instead this grid? ( empty column removed)

```
201 1 2 
202 2 
203 1 3 
204 
205 1 2 4
```

Thankyou

Comment: Is this *ms-access* with a SQL-Server behind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first use `ROW_NUMBER()` to get a running number per `numriga` within `codice` and then use either `PIVOT` or *conditional aggregation* with that:

A *mockup table* (Please create this yourself the next time)

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(codice INT, numriga INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (201,1)
,(201,2)
,(202,2)
,(203,1)
,(203,3)
,(204,NULL)
,(205,1)
,(205,2)
,(205,4);
```

The CTE is needed to apply a running number to each numriga

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.codice ORDER BY t.numriga) AS numrigaIndex
    FROM @tbl t
)
SELECT t.codice
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN t.numrigaIndex=1 THEN numriga END) AS [1]
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN t.numrigaIndex=2 THEN numriga END) AS [2]
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN t.numrigaIndex=3 THEN numriga END) AS [3]
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN t.numrigaIndex=4 THEN numriga END) AS [4]
FROM cte t
GROUP BY t.codice;
```

You can add as many lines as you might need.

The result

```
codice  1       2       3       4
------------------------------------
201     1       2       NULL    NULL
202     2       NULL    NULL    NULL
203     1       3       NULL    NULL
204     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
205     1       2       4       NULL
```